# Rename multiple files in SSH

Tags: ssh, centos

I have a Centos server.

In SSH, I downloaded multiple mp4 files in a txt with this command:

```
wget -i urls.txt
```

Now I have a list of mp4 files in a directory. The problem is those mp4 files are named:

```
65464.mp4?md5=sdokj7SRuM-OKatFmdCJJg&expires=1570102642
45421.mp4?md5=sdokj56SRuM-OKatFmdCJJg&expires=157010277842
etc...
```

How do I remove ? and everything after in all files in this directory ( For example `?md5=sdokj7SRuM-OKatFmdCJJg&expires=1570102642` ) so it would change files name to:

```
65464.mp4
45421.mp4
etc...
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution will depend upon what shell your CentOS system is running or has available. If you're running `bash`, you can do something as simple as:

```
for x in * ; do
    mv $x ${x%%\?*}
done
```

This uses `bash` [string variable manipulation](https://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/advanced_bash_scripting_guide/string-manipulation.html) techniques.

Another possible solution, still dependent upon shell features:

```
for x in * ; do
    mv $x $(echo $x | sed "s/\?.*//")
done
```

Comment: The first solution works fine. Thanks for your help.